# Sorting algorithm which returns information about items to be swapped

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm curious if there are (the are for sure but I don't know what to look for) some sort of smart sort algorithms.

What do I mean by smart sort algorithm? Lets consider an example:

I've 5 numbers in table sorted:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Then I swap 2nd and 4th, so I have:

```
1, 4, 3, 2, 5
```

As second step I swap 5th and 2nd so the final result is:

```
1, 5, 3, 2, 4
```

My expectations about the algorithm is to place final set as input (1, 5, 3, 2, 4), and as a result I'd like to get information that I should swap 2nd and 5th items and then 2nd and 4th to get list sorted.

I was thinking about usage of sorting networks: I could generate all required compare-and-swap instructions for a certain size of data and then return those swaps which would be done for input data, but maybe there some other ways?

What should I look for?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data

Comment: I guess it is harder to find the optimal swap strategy than to just sort the array.

Comment: I believe the thing you are looking for is the minimal number of swap operations required to sort a sequence. Throwing "minimum swap operations sort" into a websearch turns up enough results for a start.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the number of minimum swaps is typically not important for sorting (swaps can be done on pointers), but it is a well-known problem in its own regard.

Have a look at this question:
[Counting the adjacent swaps required to convert one permutation into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797540/counting-the-swaps-required-to-convert-one-permutation-into-another)

Or point your research to **Edit Distance**.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the problem here is that the actual swapping of the data is very expensive, but the comparison is relatively cheap.

I would first use a regular sorting algorithm to find out the locations of each element in the array. There are tons of algorithms to do that, for example quicksort or just bubble- or insertionsort.

Now we know where each element should go, and from here on out we could find the optimal series of swaps to get the original data to the sorted position.

Example in pseudocode:

```
compare(proxy1, proxy2)
  return compare(proxy1.data, proxy2.data)

smartSort(unsorted)
  swaps = []
  count = size(unsorted)
  // create a proxy for all elements
  proxiesOrig = [ new proxy(data) | for unsorted as data ]
  // and make a copy which we are going to sort
  proxiesSort = shallowCopy(proxiesOrig)
  sort(proxiesOrig)  // Do a regular sort here, using the compare function above
  // now note the location of each target
  // because we made a shallow copy, the location will also be marked in the
  // proxiesOrig list
  for i = 1 .. count
    proxiesSort[i].location = i
  // Now the proxiesOrig is the unsorted list
  // with location information to where everything needs to go
  for i = 1 .. count
    while (proxiesOrig[i].location <> i)
      // swap the proxy on location i with the one to where i needs to go
      swap(proxiesOrig, i, proxiesOrig[i].location)
      // and record it
      swaps.add(i, proxiesOrig[i].location)
  return swaps
```