# Hint required for array adjacent position swapping program

Tags: c++, sorting, swap

Can anybody give me a hint how to start with the problem below? (It's copied from exercise 3 in the link: https://wiki.ittc.ku.edu/ittc/EECS168:Lab14)

I thought of generating the permutations and checking them whether they can be obtained by swapping 2 adjacent positions and then linking and counting them, but it all seems really complicated.
The programming language I'm using is C++.
Any ideas will certainly be of great help. Thanks!

---

> **Rearranging cartons**
>
> Your school has ordered some equipment that has been delivered in a number of very heavy cartons. Each carton has a serial number and the cartons are all lined up in a row. Unfortunately, your teacher asked for the cartons to be placed in a particular sequence and you forgot to tell the people who unloaded the cartons about this. You now have to quickly restore the cartons to the correct order before the teacher comes and sees how you have messed up her instructions. Since the cartons are very heavy, you cannot carry them over long distances. In each step, all you can do is to exchange the position of two adjacent cartons. For instance, suppose the serial numbers on the cartons in the order in which they are unloaded are 34, 29, 12, 78 and 90 and the order in which the cartons were supposed to be arranged is 90, 29, 78, 34, 12. These cartons can be rearranged in the desired order with a minimum of 7 or higher exchanges, as follows:
>
> ```
> • Exchange 78, 90 — 34, 29, 12, 90, 78
> • Exchange 12, 90 — 34, 29, 90, 12, 78
> • Exchange 34, 29 — 29, 34, 90, 12, 78
> • Exchange 12, 78 — 29, 34, 90, 78, 12
> • Exchange 34, 90 — 29, 90, 34, 78, 12
> • Exchange 29, 90 — 90, 29, 34, 78, 12
> • Exchange 34, 78 — 90, 29, 78, 34, 12
> ```
>
> In this example, it can be shown that a mimimum of 7 exchanges are needed to reorder the cartons as desired. You need to rearrange them and report the number of swap **(not necessarily the minimum)** you needed with the adjacent carton in order to achieve the desired order.
>
> Input format: The first line of input is a single integer N, the total number of cartons. The second line consists of N distinct positive integers, separated by spaces, denoting the serial numbers of the N cartons in the order in which they were unloaded. The third line is another sequence of N integers, denoting the desired order in which the N cartons should be rearranged. The sequence of numbers in the third line is guaranteed to be a permutation of the sequence in the second line.
>
> Output format: The output should be a single integer, the number of exchanges required to achieve the desired sequence of cartons.
>   Here is the sample input and output corresponding to the example discussed above.
>
> ```
> Sample input:
> 5
> 34 29 12 78 90
> 90 29 78 34 12
>
> Sample output:
> 7
> ```
>
> **Note:** Your program should not print anything other than what is specified in the output format. Please remove all diagnostic print statements before making your final submission.

Comment: This is basically the Damerau distance (i.e., what the Damerau added in the Damerau–Levenshtein edit distance metric).

Comment: Are you a KU student?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the Damerau distance.

Comment: @Inisheer No! I'm about to graduate from high school:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, you're not required to report the *minimum* number of swaps, just *any* sufficient number of swaps. This brings to mind two strategies:

1. Ignore the second and third lines of input, and immediately print N^2 and return. Technically this conforms to spec! But you wouldn't be able to prove to an auditor that it's possible to arrange the cartons with *exactly* N^2 steps. In fact, you might have the wrong [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation). So if you want to be less sneaky...
2. Find the carton that's supposed to go in the first spot, and swap it to the left until it gets there. Find the carton that's supposed to go in the second spot, and swap it to the left until it gets there. Repeat until done. Keep track of the steps and report it at the end. This is probably not optimal, but it shouldn't be too hard to code.

Comment: If I want the minimum number of steps, what do I do? Otherwise, I like your logic. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried out your logic, and I am getting the minimum number of steps! I was wondering if it works all the time....

Comment: I suppose it does! There's more discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797540/counting-the-swaps-required-to-convert-one-permutation-into-another