# How to compare two paths

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, swap

My data structure is a *path* represented by a list of cities. If, for example, the cities are

```
A, B, C, D
```

A possible configuration could be: `A, B, D, C` or `D, C, A, B`.

I need two compare two paths in order to find the differences between these two, in such a way that the output of this procedure returns the set of swapping operations necessary to transform the second path into the first one.

For example, given the following paths:

```
X = {A, B, D, C}
Y = {D, C, A, B}
indexes = {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

A possible way to transform the path `Y` into `X` would be the set of the following swaps: `{0-2, 1-3}`.

```
{D, C, A, B} --> [0-2] --> {A, C, D, B} --> [1-3] --> {A, B, D, C}
```

Is there any known (and fast) algorithm that allows to compute this set?

Comment: How long is the path? BFS (or A* search algorithm) can do it, but it will take exponential time.

Comment: @amit the order of magnitude is 2, thus less than 1000 elements.

Comment: if the result exists, it's possible to solve (fast) using sorting algorithm with custom key function.

Comment: @SashaMN would be best defining this algorithm or showing an example

Comment: @gliderkite it can be done in O(N) also, using counting sort like algorithm) It's not so hard, I only give you an idea.

Comment: @SashaMN Sorting (counting or general purpose) is not guaranteed to provide the shortest series of swaps needed to convert one list to the other, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @amit My second approach guaranteed, no matter, Edgar Rokyan gave the answer.

Comment: @SashaMN your second approach is a well known sorting algorithm that does not return the swap operations that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks like a problem of counting the minimal number of swaps to transform one permutation to another.

In fact it's a well known problem. The key idea is to create new permutation `P` such that `P[i]` is the index of `X[i]` city in the `Y`. Then you just calculate the total number of cycles `C` in the `P`. The answer is the `len(X) - C`, where `len(X)` is the size of `X`.

In your case `P` looks like: `3, 4, 1, 2`. It has two cycles: `3, 1` and `4, 2`. So the answer is `4 - 2 = 2`.

Total complexity is linear.

For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20651773/5507349). It explains this algorithm in more details.

**EDIT**

Okay, but how we can get swaps, and not only their number? Note, that in this solution we reorder each cycle independently doing `N - 1` swaps if the length of cycle is `N`. So, if you have cycle `v(0), v(1), ..., v(N - 1), v(N)` you just need to swap `v(N), v(N - 1)`, `v(N - 1), v(N - 2)`, ..., `v(1), v(0)`. So you swap cycle elements in reverse order.

Also, if you have `C` cycles with lengths `L(1), L(2), ..., L(C)` the number of swaps is `L(1) - 1 + L(2) - 1 + ... + L(C) - 1 = L(1) + L(2) + ... + L(C) - C = LEN - C` where `LEN` is the length of permutation.

Comment: I thought, not only the number of swap operations, but the swap operations themselves should be the result? I doubt, that this will be possible in linear time complexity.

Comment: @Ctx the algorithm is trivial, if you understand, that you need exactly N - 1 swaps to transform one cycle with length N.

Comment: @SashaMN If it's so trivial, be so kind and write an answer with the actual algorithm for the OPs problem which has O(n) worst-case time complexity. I doubt you (indeed anyone) will succeed.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I still do not see how this should work in O(n). Not even the first step (P[i] is the index of X[i] city in Y) is doable in O(n). Or how would you achieve that?

Comment: You can iterate over `Y` and set for `Y[i]` `T[Y[i]] = i`. Then iterate over `X` and set `P[i]=T[X[i]]`. Something like this. You can adopt it in any suitable way.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that. Ok, this indeed might be working, thanks for explaining ;)

Comment: @Ctx Nice! It should works. Unfortunately I don't know a strict mathematical proof... But you can try to google Cayley distance and it's connection to permutations as it's mentioned in the answer from the link I posted. As I remember I solved similar problem on Timus online judge a few years ago and this algorithm was accepted.

Comment: What is the name of the algorithm? Where can I find any reference?

Comment: @gliderkite I doubt that It has a name. May be I just don't know... There're many discussions on SO and other resources concerning this problem. For example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987605/minimum-number-of-swaps-needed-to-change-array-1-to-array-2