# Count different permutations after at most 2 swaps

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming

How do I solve the 2nd part of [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/swappermutation) if the input array may contain **repeated** numbers and the value of **K = 2**

Examples:

```
1 2 3 4     ans-18
1 2 3 4 5   ans-46
1 1 2 2 3   ans-26
1 1 1 2 2   ans-10
1 1 2 2 3 4 ans-56
```

**My approach:**
First, I count the different numbers in the array, then calculate an answer using DP (please see editorial of this problem).
Using those numbers, I tried some permutations, but the answer is incorrect.

I have already solve it with Time Complexity O(n^4),, is there any more efficient solution for this problem

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797540/counting-the-swaps-required-to-convert-one-permutation-into-another

Comment: What is your work so far? Depending on your algorithm, I don't see why it wouldn't work with duplicates. Also, your English is a little tough, are you saying that you're converting your arrays into Sets? If so, that won't work because you're losing elements.

Comment: @goodguy5 no,, i am not converting into set,, sorry but i don't think that algorithm will work if array may contain repeated numbers because that algorithm works on length of array not on what are the values in that array ,,

Comment: @goodguy5 that algorithm is giving output 46 on 1 2 3 4 5(1st input) and 1 1 2 2 3(2nd input) but 46 is not correct answer for 2nd input

Comment: Alright, I understand. Give me a bit to put something up, though I would also still like to see your work.

Comment: Could anyone chime in if this String tag belongs here? Seems incorrect, but I'm not sure. I see how you COULD apply the same logic to sorting a string of characters/numbers, but still...

Comment: I've found a better solution that's increases performance by selective swapping. But, I can't figure out the order. It seems like n^(k+1), but it improves for higher values of k.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Code will be in Python, because it's easy. The logic should work for any language (more or less).

To reiterate the question:

> You are given an array A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]:
>   How many sequences (S2) can you get after at most k swaps on A?
>
> An adjacent swap can be made between two elements of the Array A, A[i] and A[i+1] or A[i] and A[i-1].
>   A swap otherwise can be between any two elements of the array A[i] and A[j] ∀ 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N, i ≠ j.

Let's address what we need to do:

- Make a collection of lists (I'll use a list of lists)
- Make some function that manipulates the list
- Find all results of swapping any two elements of all the original list

  - Repeat N-1 times for latest iterations of the original list

Now, I can address each "requirement", one at a time.

1. A list of lists

   - I like to set up my list variables that I'll test with later: `D = [1,2,3,4]`, for example
   - `master_list  = []`
2. My functions will be `perm_count(orig_list, k)` and `permuter(my_list)`

   - perm_count will be our "manager", adding elements to the list of lists
   - permuter will be doing our legwork, finding the swaps and returning them to perm_count
3. We'll use a loop to look through all the lists in the previous iteration and find all the swaps there-in. (you'll see in the code)

   - One thing to note is that, depending on the language, it's important to take a "snapshot" of the list with you start each "k" loop, or else the list will grow while you're working on it.
   - stuff it all in another loop and off we go!

Python code used in [pythonfiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com)

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]  
B = [1,1,2,2,3]  
C = [1,2,3]  
D = [1,2,3,4]

def perm_count(orig_list, k):

master_list  = []
master_list.append(list(orig_list))
while k > 0:
    big_list = list(master_list) #"Snapshot" to ensure list-stability
    for each_list in big_list: #Looks at all the permutations from the previous "generations"
        for each_temp_list in permuter(each_list):
            if each_temp_list not in master_list:
                master_list.append(each_temp_list)
                #our masterlist now contains all the distinct lists from this run
                #If we run it again (the "k"), we get 2-swap combinations
                #and so on...

    k-=1

total_count = len(master_list)
print sorted(master_list) #If you need a sanity check, feel free to leave out
return total_count
#end perm_count

def permuter(my_list):#returns a list of lists
    lists_list = []
    #The below loop block returns all possible 1-swap combinations.
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        for j in range(len(my_list)):
            temp_list = my_list[:]
            if i != j:
                temp_list[i],temp_list[j] = temp_list[j],temp_list[i]
            if temp_list not in lists_list:
                lists_list.append(list(temp_list))

    return lists_list
#end permuter

print perm_count(B,2)
```

Comment: this is a very simple approach with time complexity O(n^(2*k)) ,, i already made this solution,, i need some efficient solution in O(n*log(n) or in O(n)

Comment: @Mrs_U, Also, I think that what you're asking is impossible. I'm not a Big O master, but O(n) is definitely out. You have go through the list at least k times, and the list grows with each iteration of k. I don't see how you can do better than O(n^k) or maybe O(log(n)^k)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't answer now, Its question of ongoing contest.

```
[contest link][1]
```

https://www.codechef.com/MARCH16/problems/SEATSTR2