# finding inversions of a number array using divide and conquer

Tags: python, algorithm, inversion

I came across [a post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987605/minimum-number-of-swaps-needed-to-change-array-1-to-array-2/2989341#2989341) where the algorithm is implemented in python code .This is a direct implementation of the pseudocode in [this article](http://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~piak/teaching/algo/algo2008/count-inv.htm) .

However,in the pseudocode ,there is a line where count is incremented by the number of remaining elements in array 'a'.In the above python code,it is given as

```
count += len(a) - i
```

can't we do the same by

```
count += len(a[i:])
```

Also,instead of

```
c += a[i:] + b[j:]
```

I wrote,

```
c.append(a[i:])
c.append(b[j:])
```

In total my version looks like this

```
def merge(left,right):
    i=0
    j=0
    count=0
    c=[]
    while i<len(left) and j<len(right):
        c.append(min(left[i],right[j]))
        if right[j]< left[i]:
            count+=len(left[i:])
            j+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    c.append(left[i:])
    c.append(right[j:])
    return count,c


def dnc(input):
    if len(input)==1:
        return 0,input
    mid=len(input)/2
    left=input[:mid]
    right=input[mid:]
    l,left=dnc(left)
    r,right=dnc(right)
    m,result=merge(left,right)
    count=l+r+m
    return count,result
```

Alas!,when I compute this on a sorted array,I get 3 instead of 0

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    input =[1,2,3,4,5]
    ct,res=dnc(input)
    print ct
```

What have I done wrong? can someone help me find out?

Comment: So... which one is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I can suggest:

- Don't do `count += len(a[i:])`. It's slower than your original and is unnecessarily complicating the logic. I would instead cache `len(a)` as `len_a` and calculate it once outside of your loop, as `a` doesn't seem to be modified.
- `c += a[i:] + b[j:]` is the same as `c.extend(a[i:])` and `c.extend(b[j:])`. `extend` appends the *contents* of the list to `c` while `append` appends the list itself, which might be causing your problem.

Comment: you are right..I didn't think about extend at all! thanks a bunch