# Minimum swaps required to get sorted array

Tags: python

I have tried the code below for minimum swaps. What's wrong as I get only 2/13 test cases passing

```
def minimumSwaps(popularity):
    temp = [0] * (len(popularity) + 1)
    for pos, val in enumerate(popularity):
        temp[val] = pos
        pos += 1
    swaps = 0
    for i in range(len(popularity)):
        if popularity[i] != i+1:
            swaps += 1
            t = popularity[i]
            popularity[i] = i+1
            popularity[temp[i+1]] = t
            temp[t] = temp[i+1]
    return swaps
```

Comment: What type of input is being provided?

Comment: Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152322/compute-the-minimal-number-of-swaps-to-order-a-sequence/15152602#15152602