# Minimum Swaps to sort an array in descending order with time complexity O(nlogn) in java

Tags: sorting, swap

An array has elements like a1,a2,a3...an  with constraints 1 <= ai <= n.

I need to find minimum number of swaps required to sort an array in descending order.

I was able to get a solution with selection sort but it has a time complexity of O(n^2) but i need an efficient solution.

Please refer to the below link and help me to find it in the descending order.
[Compute the minimal number of swaps to order a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152322/compute-the-minimal-number-of-swaps-to-order-a-sequence/15152602#15152602)