# Most effective method of swapping elements of an array after comparing it with other array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let's say we have two arrays:
Array a1 and Array a2.

'a1' and 'a2' are similar in a way such that both have the same size and same elements but elements don't appear in the same order.

What will be the most effective way of comparing both arrays and finding out the minimum number of swaps required to bring the array 'a1' in the same order as 'a2'?

For example:

```
int a1[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int a2[5] = { 2, 3, 1, 5, 4};
```

Hence the minimum number of swaps required is: 3

In steps:

swap 1: a1[0] <-> a1[1]

swap 2: a1[1] <-> a1[2]

swap 3: a1[3] <-> a1[4]

So, finally a1 will contain { 2, 3, 1, 5, 4}

Comment: Are the numbers the integers from 1 to n ?

Comment: there is known algorithm for this: [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) . Although it is a little more general. I don't know if for your restrictions can be improved or if there is another one faster for your restrictions.

Comment: (Sorry, I think this should be a comment, but I don't have 50 reputations to make one) Unless I'm missing something, this has been asked before and you will likely find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987605/minimum-number-of-swaps-needed-to-change-array-1-to-array-2

Answer (score 0):

```
int numofchanges = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArrays; i++)
{
    int arr3[] = arr1;
    for(int n = 0; n < sizeOfArrays; n++)
    {
         arr3[i] = arr1[n];
         if(arr3[i] == arr2[i])
         {
             int tmp = arr1[i];
             arr1[i] = arr1[n];
             arr1[n] = tmp;
             numofchanges++;
         }
    }
}
```

**WARRNING** this wont run is something like pseudo code

the variable numofchanges will hold the number of changes and arr1 now will be arr2

i hope this was helpful